# iPad Multitasking: dismiss the keyboard running in another app

Tags: ios, keyboard, ipados, split-screen-multitasking, ipados15

### Scenario

Consider e.g. a default Calendar app that has some content displayed at the very bottom.

Now let's run it in the multitasking mode, so that it looks like this:

[image]

### Problem

And now let's open a keyboard in another app, e.g. Safari:

[image]

The keyboard obscures the content, so when the user starts dragging a scrollview in the app on the right, the content at the bottom couldn't be reach.

A normal way to dismiss the keyboard would be to execute the following code:

```
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)),
                                        to: nil,
                                        from: nil,
                                        for: nil)
```

However, in this case, it has no effect, as the keyboard is shown in the other application (that I don't have control of).

Is there any way to dismiss a keyboard in this scenario or do I have to accommodate to this scenario via UX / design change of the app on the right?